# Cisco ISR 4431 ACL Blocking when it should permit ssh traffic

Tags: networking, cisco, configuration, router, ios

The intention here was to create a access-list that would permit any device with an IP from two different /24 subnets (lets call them  192.168.1.0 and 192.168.2.0) to SSH into the ISR while denying anyother IPs. so I created the following standard access list.

```
access-list 1 permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 1 permit 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255
```

Then while connected to the 192.168.1.0 subnet I tried to SSH into the ISR via putty and get a error stating the connection was refused.

When the following lines are removed I am able to SSH into the ISR without issue. (i have already done the SSH Configuration on the ISR to use a Large RSA key and to use SSH 2.0)

```
line vty 0 4
 access-class 1 in
line vty 5 15
 access-class 1 in
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this simple access-list is blocking traffic when it should not? I am a bit of a novice with Cisco IOS so it probably some tiny detail I missed.
Below is the current config of the vty lines and the ACLs:

```
!
access-list 1 permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 1 permit 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255
!
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
 stopbits 1
line aux 0
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 access-class 1 in
 login authentication local
 transport input ssh
line vty 5 15
 access-class 1 in
 login authentication local
 transport input ssh
!
!
end
```

Comment: See [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/44721/telnet-or-ssh-into-a-cisco-router).

Comment: Not seeing anything new there, that guys issue was he did not configure the  RSA key and did not specify the "transport input ssh" in his vty lines. I have all that specified. Only thing i can see that is different is a slight tweak to the access list in defining it as  ip access-list instead of just access-list.

Comment: Don't you have to apply the access list to an interface or to a vlan? instead of the line vty?

Comment: Not sure but all the guides I have found say to do it this way. If i were to apply it to an interface i would need to use an extended access-list to allow me to only filter port 22 or by ssh protocol.

Comment: Not to say that would not work. I may give that a try

Comment: It looks OK from the snippet we're seeing.  Can you add an explicit "access-list 1 deny any log" statement to the ACL to see what's getting dropped?  If nothing else this should confirm you're coming from the right subnet.

Comment: Have you tried `login local` instead of `login authentication local`, if you are trying to authenticate with local users?

Comment: Echoing rnxrx, you should add a deny any as your last ACE entry.  The logged deny might give you more clues.

Comment: shogo i will try that. as for the deny any entry according to cisco's documentation that is implied at the end of all ACLs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ssh to the router through MGMT interface,you must add **vrf-also** after the command in new version, just as following:

```
line vty 0 4
 access-class 1 in vrf-also
 login authentication local
 transport input ssh
line vty 5 15
 access-class 1 in vrf-also
 login authentication local
 transport input ssh
```